# topLayoutGuide equivalent in UIPresentationController?

Tags: ios, autolayout, statusbar, uipresentationcontroller, uilayoutguide

I have a custom transition for presenting a view controller and I use a `UIPresentationController` subclass to perform the presentation.

In the presentation controller I add a couple of subviews to its `containerView` (the chrome). I would like to constrain one of them with something like the `topLayoutGuide` in order to account for the height of any top bars (like the status bar).

However, `UIPresentationController` is not a `UIViewController` subclass and as such it doesn't have a `topLayoutGuide` property. I tried constraining the views with the `presentingViewController`'s and the `presentedViewController`'s `topLayoutGuide` but the app crashes because they are not part of the same view hierarchy.

**So is there any way to position subviews inside the presentation controller's `containerView` at its top while still accounting for the height of any top bars?**

Answer (score 0):

By trial and error I found out that for `topLayoutGuide` to work it is important that the added view controllers view height is not larger than the screen size  height. In `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning` in `func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning)`
set:

```
toVC.view.frame = transitionContext.finalFrame(for: toVC)
```